# App crashes with [sender tag]

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ibaction

I have a button within interface builder that has a '0' tag on it. The button has a method linked to it called `-(IBAction) doTest:(id)sender`.

I have the `doTest` method within my .m file as shown below:

```
-(IBAction) doTest:(id)sender
{
    int currentSelection= [sender tag];

    if (currentSelection == 0)
    {
         // do something
    }
}
```

However my app crashes with the following error message and I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
[groceryapp doTest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc29c00
2012-03-04 20:26:10.155 groceries[4627:707] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[grocery doTest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc29c00'
```

Comment: Where are you setting the button's action? It's trying to send the wrong message (`doTest`, not `doTest:`).

Comment: Ah Figured it out. Stupid mistake. Thanks boys!

Comment: Since `0` is the default tag for a view, and also if sender is `nil`, then `[sender nil]` will return `0`, you should consider using a different value for the tag, too.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong message.

doTest vs doTest: